# OPENACC How to handle a library function in a #pragma acc routine

Tags: openacc

I have to call the `<stdlib.h>` function `exit()` inside this routine:

```
#pragma acc routine(Check) seq
int Check (double **u, char *str)
{
  
  for (int i = beg; i <= end; i++) {
  for (int v = 0; v < vend; v++) {
    if (isnan(u[i][v])) {
      
      #pragma acc routine(Here) seq
      Here (i,NULL);
    
      #pragma acc routine(exit)
      exit(1);
    }
  }}
  return 0;
}
```

I get the error:

**nvlink error   : Undefined reference to 'exit' in 'tools.o'**

Usually I solve this problem by adding the routine `#pragma acc routine` before the body of the function but in this case I'm dealing with a library function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All routines called from the device, need a device callable version of the routine.  Often system routines do not have device callable versions, including "exit", so can't be used.

Though, you can't exit a host application from device code, so you may want to rethink this portion of the code.  Instead of using "exit", you'll want to capture errors and then abort once execution has returned to the host.